# Can't use `svelte/animate` to make a list item fly into a header

Tags: svelte

I'm trying to get a material design style thing where the location name would fly into the header. It seems that Svelte can't figure out that the two things are connected.

demo: https://svelte.dev/repl/865750b1ffb642f59d317747bd9f3534?version=3.4.4

Basically the way I tried to get it to work was by having a locaiton list like so:

```html
     {#each visibleLocations as location (location.id)}
        <div
          on:click={() => (selectedLocation = location)}
          class="location"
          animate:flip
          out:send={{ key: location.id }}
          in:receive={{ key: selectedLocation.id }}>
          <div class="name"> {location.name} </div>
        </div>
      {/each}
```

Then I had the header which looked like this. Note I had to wrap it in an each block to get the compiler to let me do this. Naturally this makes me thing that I was doing something a bit wrong

```html
    {#each selectedLocaitonList as chosenLocaiton (chosenLocaiton.id)}
        <div
          class="header"
          animate:flip
          in:send={{ key: chosenLocaiton.id }}
          out:receive={{ key: chosenLocaiton.id }}>
          {#if chosenLocaiton.id}
            <button on:click={() => (selectedLocation = { id: null })}>◀️</button>
             {chosenLocaiton.name}
          {:else}Pick a Location near you{/if}
        </div>
      {/each}
```

Maybe it's that selectedLocation isn't getting figured out to be the same thing? I'm not sure how it figures this out, I was hoping it would be via the ID.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`in` should always be paired with `receive` and `out` should always be paired with `send`; `in:send` will always give strange results. You've also got a mismatch between locations here:

```
out:send={{ key: location.id }}
in:receive={{ key: selectedLocation.id }}
```

They both need to be the same.

The `animate` directive is for reordering items *within* a list — since in this case, the first list is always going from `[x]` to `[y]` and the second one is always going from `[]` to `[x, y, z]` there are no common elements to animate, so it's not the right place to use that directive.

When using `crossfade`, the sent/received elements should be the same dimensions, and ideally should look ok when placed atop one another (i.e. type in the same place relative to the element's bounding box, etc). Here, the `<button>` element makes things differently sized.

In other words, something a bit more like this: https://svelte.dev/repl/f4386ec88df34e3b9a6b513e19374824?version=3.4.4

Unfortunately, there's still a bit of a visual glitch — because we're using a scale transform as a fallback, the *layout* doesn't transition, meaning that the outer border snaps in and out of place rather than resizing smoothly. We can use a `slide` transition instead, but then the sliding element and the crossfading element seem to trip up over each other. In either case, there seems to be a phantom element sticking around in the DOM and upsetting the layout. I'm not sure if this is a Svelte bug (and if so, whether it's fixable) without further investigation, so I've raised an issue: https://github.com/sveltejs/svelte/issues/2957

Comment: Is there a potential to support this use-case better @rich-harris? Meaning making one element fly to a new place like a header or a modal?

Comment: that's exactly what `crossfade` is designed to accomplish

Answer (score 1):

Turns out if I swap the `out` and `in` then it works as expected. Not sure why this is, so a better answer is desired.